# Visual Studio "Organize Usings | Remove and Sort" falsely reports error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In various code files of various projects, Visual Studio sometimes gives an error message when I tell it to remove and sort the usings of the code file. The message:

> "Your project or one of its references does not currently build. If you
>   continue with this operation, required usings may be removed."

However, this is not true. Required usings are not removed when telling VS to continue, and the project *does* build.

I have Googled this issue, looked in MSDN, and tried to figure out why I get this on certain code files but not others, but no no avail.

Has anyone else encountered this, and if so, any ideas what this is about?

Ps. I am running VS 2012 Ultimate, but I saw this from at least 2005.

Comment: "Required usings are not removed" - that's still in line with the warning. Note that the warning doesn't say that they *will* be removed, just that they *may* be removed.

Comment: True, but the first part of the warning is false. Why I get this on certain code files is perplexing.

Comment: I had the same problem in VS2012 Premium and disabled the "VS2010 Power Tools" extension I had installed. After a restart (of VS) the problem disappeared. Re-enabling the extension, however, did no longer cause any problems, so I'm not sure if this is of any help (you might not even have that extension installed...).

Comment: Thanks @Gorgsenegger. I don't have PowerTools installed. In fact, I had this problem "out the box". This is a real mystery to me.

Comment: A restart of my PC (restarting Visual Studio was not sufficient) fixed this for me. But then, it had been running for a good number of days if not weeks.

Comment: Did you have connection between errors and number of projects in solution or types of projects in solution. For me it only has errors for c++/cli projects and it seams that this only happens in large solutions (>150) projects.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error message can come up erroneously, and is a known issue documented out on Microsoft Connect:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785457/remove-unused-usings-falsely-reports-that-project-does-not-build-for-certain-files

It will not be fixed with the current MSBuild compiler, but will be fixed with Roslyn.

Workaround:

> You can disable the warning message by going to Tools->Options->Text
>   Editor->C#->Advanced->"Warn if build errors exist when organizing
>   usings".
>
> Keep in mind this has the downside that it won't protect you any more
>   if your solution really does not build.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the data. I can't believe this bug has been around for so many years and is only fixed in a yet-to-be-released version of VS.

Comment: They've been working on Roslyn for quite awhile now, so I'm guessing they crossed a line in the sand somewhere and decided to stop trying to fix issues in the existing compiler.  FWIW I've been running with that warning turned off for months and it hasn't really bitten me yet.

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue and it turned out there was an invalidly formatted class reference in an XML comment. I had something like this

```
<see cref="List{T">
```

Note the missing '}' character at the end. It was driving me crazy until I found that.

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with the Productivity Power Tools installed, and this was happening every time I saved because I had the "remove and sort usings on save" option turned on. I really like this feature and was on the point of turning it off due to these warnings, thinking it was buggy. Now I know what to look for when I get them.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm getting it on a file with no XML and on one with valid XML. Did you find that this consistently occurred on the file with broken XML?

Comment: Yes, it occurred every time I tried to save the file until I was able to track down the missing bracket, and that fixed it. That's the only case so far where I've had it consistently appear in a file even though my project was building just fine. I've definitely seen it in other places but could not tell you if it's the same issue or something else. I will update here if I run across other instances.

Comment: In my particular case it was: `<exception cref="">Type.Here</exception>`. Not my code but annoying nonetheless!

Comment: This definitely seems to be related to XML documentation.  In my case I had: `<see cref="System.Func&lt;T, int, bool&gt;"/>` - changing it to `<see cref="System.Func&lt;T, Int32, Boolean&gt;"/>` fixed the problem.  I have no idea why that fixed it.  I could have sworn I have used type aliases successfully in the past but maybe not.

Comment: For me it was `<see cref="System.Net.Http.ObjectContent."/>` with the extra period. So, tally another one for the invalid XML documentation